# Java console application with long operation that is abortable

Tags: java, windows, console

I'm programming a console application with Java that can be used to monitor a certain website. This operation can be infinite, until it is aborted. Just pressing CTRL + C to abort it does not work, because the application remains in running in the background. (I'm using Windows, but it should be portable.)

Comment: Why couldn't you just wait for user input and kill the program if user enters a certain word?

Comment: @Austin How is this possible with Java?

Comment: Looks like http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005 could help you out.

Comment: @Austin add that as your answer and I'll accept it - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why couldn't you just wait for user input and kill the program if user enters a certain word?

Looks like http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005 could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register a shutdownhook? That is called by the JVM when you interrupt it. In there you could cleanly terminate your application.

One thing to remember: any (background) thread that you start should be marked as a daemon thread using `Thread.setDaemon(true)` otherwise the JVM will not terminate because it only terminates if all non-daemon threads are finished. Maybe that's why your application stays "in the background" even if you press Ctrl-C

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1.Have a boolean variable to determine when the user wants to kill the program.

2.Create an infinite loop to monitor the website, and inside that check the state of the
  boolean variable.

eg:

```
boolean isGoing = true;

   String s = null;

    public void monitor(){

    while(isGoing){

       if(s.compareToIgnoreCase(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()) == 0){

        break;
    }

   // monitor here..................


  }
}
```